# How to add double over dot in xlabel in matlab

Tags: matlab, latex

I have a simple quick question, does anyone know how to add double over-dot in `xlabel()` in MATLAB?
I know how to add a single over-dot as follows:

```
xlabel('$\dot{\phi}$','interpreter','latex')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ddot` instead of `dot`:

```
xlabel('$\ddot{\phi}$','interpreter','latex')
```